# Navbar size increases on small screen

Tags: navbar

I have a header and is overlapped on navbar. I liked it that way.
but problem is, when I go on site from smaller devices navbar-toggle increases navbar size how to fix this.
my temp website
rank.inserver.in/starofdavid

just try to minmize your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your button is outside the navigation header like this:

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><div>
    </div>
    <button></button>
</nav>
```

Change it to:

```
<nav>
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="navbar-brand"><div>
        <button></button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

You could also use css media query to style mobile or tablet view 
[Media Query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)